# How to integrate trace32 with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, trace32

I want to automate trace32. It is running perfectly on the command line but not from Jenkins.

Comment: Trace32 by Microsoft or TRACE32 by Lauterbach?

Comment: Can you show us more detail? What configuration do you have at present to integrate this thing into Jenkins?

Comment: It is Lauterbach TRACE32. Actually i have already automate it. But the problem that i m facing is when i build my project in Jenkins then it shows a message "Interactive Service detection" and when i click on view this message it displays TRACE32 loading the elf file and running. Now i don't want this message to pop up. I want to show Trace32 running automatically with successful build . I don't want any user interface like click on "view this message" . Can you please tell me how can i do that.

Comment: how are you running your Jenkins slave that TRACE32 runs on? for GUI apps (assuming windows), you need to run in an user session (not as a service) to get a GUI (which brings other problems)

Answer (score 4):

In your TRACE32 configuration file (config.t32) find the line starting with "SCREEN=" and change it to "SCREEN=OFF". If there is no line starting with "SCREEN=" add a and empty line at the end of the file and then add the line "SCREEN=OFF". (Empty lines do play a role in config.t32)

This will completely disable the GUI of TRACE32. In this configuration you can only do actions triggered by the PRACTICE script initially loaded by TRACE32 (t32.cmm or "-s" command line option) or you can trigger actions with the remote API. Don't forget to close TRACE32 with the QUIT command at the end of your PRACTICE script.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But i don't want to close the GUI of TRACE32. I want to show it but automatically. As i said in my previous reply that there is an "interactive service detection message" that popup whenever i click on "build now" button in Jenkins. When i click on this message then it shows me the TRACE32 GUI. I want to show TRACE32 GUI without clicking on the message. Could  you please tell me how to do that. Once again thanks for your answers.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately I don't not know the answer in that case. I have a very hight knowledge about TRACE32 but I don't know much about Jenkins. I know that it is possible, since I know people who do tests with TRACE32 triggered by Jenkins. As far as I know they use Ruby-scripts to start TRACE32 from Jenkins.